# How to use AWS cognito token in the frontend to hide and show page menu?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, authentication, frontend, amazon-cognito

I am building a website using HTML, CSS, and Javascript. It is hosted on AWS. Some features are used from AWS. One of which is Cogito which I use for authentication. Now I successfully created user authentication tokens: Pool Id, Pool ARN, and App client id. It uses OAuth2 authentication. My question is how do i handle these server side validations into the front end? I want to hide and show certain menus to users based on their login info. Is there a script that i need to include in the frontend?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the framework you are using. For a Cognito web app that uses Spring BOOT, you can achieve this functionality by using these tags:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">
    <p>You must log in with Amazon Connito to access this AWS Web Application.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" th:href="@{/oauth2/authorization/cognito}" role="button">
        Log in using <b>Amazon Cognito</b>
    </a>
</div>
```

Everyone can see that. Then to show content for authenticated users - you use:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
 <h1>A secure AWS Web application</h1>
 <p>Hello user <strong th:text="${#authentication.getName()}"></strong></p>
```

Comment: I never heard of Spring BOOT before. Thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: But what if I am not using any frameworks? just plain html, css, javascript. Is there anyway I can handle the token securely in the frontend?

Comment: There are various online resources like this one that will help -- https://dzone.com/articles/build-a-secure-javascript-app-in-20-minutes